# Uso da tecla tab no ckeditor

Tags: ckeditor, tabela-html

Estou utilizando o ckeditor em um sistema que estou desenvolvendo e tenho a seguinte dúvida. 
Tem como habilitar a tecla <kbd>tab</kbd> no ckeditor?

Comment: Oi, Ricardo, o site não funciona como fórum ou rede social. Nossa assinatura é o box de usuário abaixo do post, e os agradecimentos são em forma de votos positivos.

Answer (score 2):

Encontrei a resposta que estava precisando. Para quem se interessar, faça o seguinte:

1. abrir o arquivo ckeditor.js
2. encontre dentro do arquivo a palavra "**c.config.tabSpaces||0**"
3. então altere para "**c.config.tabSpaces||5**" ou qualquer outro numero. No meu caso deixei 5.

Neste caso, quando estou digitando um texto (CKEDITOR) ao teclar "**TAB**" o cursor pula 5 espaços, uso isso sempre no início de cada parágrafo.